# How to postgresql role conntect special time

Tags: postgresql, triggers

How to do the role of PostgreSQL conntect special time

For example：

The role 'abc' only conntect PostgreSQL from AM 8:00 to AM 12:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that comes to mind is a regularly scheduled operating system task that either runs `GRANT/REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE` or edits `pg_hba.conf` regularly.